# 2-way switches and LED Light glowing faintly when both switches turned 'on'

Tags: led

I have an LED light on the landing operated by 2 way switches upstairs and down.

When both 2-way switches are in the 'OFF' position the light goes out completely.

When the light is turned off by both switches being in the 'ON' position, the light continues to glow dimly until the light is turned on again.

What can I do to make the LED light go out completely which ever way it is turned off?

Answer (score 2):

Possibility #1:  These are not normal switches.  These have some sort of active (powered) function, such as glowing handle, dimmer, motion sensor, smart switch of some kind, etc.  They power themselves via the old "leak a little current through the incandescent bulb, it won't care" strategy, which does not play well with any modern bulb.   The solution is visit the electrical supply and get two basic switches.

Possibility #2 (less likely IMO): There is something broken in how the circuit is wired.  There are right ways and wrong ways to wire 2-ways (or as we call them in the US, 3-ways). You may want to pop covers off lamp and switches and double check everything against the "proper" diagrams you'll find on the web. In doing this, pay attention to function moreso than wire color.  It doesn't matter which color you use for which function, as long as the functions are hooked up correctly.